# Python socket and Angular5

Tags: python, angular, sockets

Please help to find the reason of issue. 
I have a simple daemon on python with socket on 9999 port, it's working correctly and returning on each GET request some info. 
In the second side I have a Angular application, with the button which running function of GET, but it's not working... Please help to clarify why.

Class on Angular :

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  apiURL:string = 'hostname:9999';

  constructor(private http:Http) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  httpRequest() {
    this.http.get(this.apiURL).subscribe(outJson => console.log(outJson));
  }
}
```

And error which I'm getting on browser :

```
View_HeaderComponent_0
ng:///AppModule/HeaderComponent.ngfactory.js:58:8
proxyClass compiler.js:14640
DebugContext_.prototype.logError core.js:15030
ErrorHandler.prototype.handleError core.js:1488
dispatchEvent core.js:9994
renderEventHandlerClosure/< core.js:10611:29
decoratePreventDefault/<
platform-browser.js:2628:25 ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask zone.js:367
onInvokeTaskv core.js:4744
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask zone.js:366
Zone.prototype.runTask zone.js:166
ZoneTask/this.invoke zone.js:420
```

P.S. The reason in Angular, cause request is not coming to python at all.

And this error also getting :

```
[WDS] Disconnected!
vendor.bundle.js:35042:10
log http://host/vendor.bundle.js:35042:10
closevclient:104
socket/sock.onclose socket.js:15
EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent eventtarget.js:51
SockJS.prototype._close/<  main.js:356
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask zone.js:367
Zone.prototype.runTask zone.js:166
ZoneTask/this.invoke zone.js:420
scheduleTask/data.args[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason in the next: 
When you're doing request on external resource you should add "http://" on your URL, because when you're making :

```
this.http.get(host.com:9999)
```

it's looking for "host.com/host.com:9999"